# CSV to Google Sheets python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a CSV that I want to put into a google sheet into sheet3 of many. I was hoping someone can help me complete this code. I am using Google API. So far I have gotten the csv to upload to the google drive. Now I would like to change the code to update a specific google sheet in sheet3 instead of creating a new sheet. Bellow you will find the code that I am using to create a new sheet with the CSV data.

```
# Import Csv to Google Drive
import os
import glob

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)  

 
# line used to change the directory
os.chdir(r'DIRECTORY OF CSV')

list_of_files = glob.glob('DIRECTORY OF CSV\*') # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)

upload_file_list = [latest_file]
for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': 'THE GOOGLE ID'}]})
    # Read file and set it as the content of this instance.
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload() # Upload the file.
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `a specific google sheet in sheet3`. What does it mean? And, in your script, it seems that multiple CSV files are uploaded. In this case, how do you want to put all CSV data on the specific sheet?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try and explain. So I have a google sheet named Test and inside this sheet I have sheet1-10. I would like to paste the info from this one CSV in to Sheet3 in A1. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm in your situation. About `I have a google sheet named Test and inside this sheet I have sheet1-10`, you have a Google Spreadsheet that the Spreadsheet title is "Test". If my understanding is correct, there are no Spreadsheets of the same Spreadsheet title in the folder `THE GOOGLE ID`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yea you are correct. If more than one CSV file then I would like to be able to specify the sheet#,  still with in the same google spreadsheet. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `If more than one CSV file then I would like to be able to specify the sheet#, still with in the same google spreadsheet.`, I cannot imagine about this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: By the way, in your situation, I think that it is required to use Sheets API. Can you use Sheets API?

Comment: I am pullin info from an SQL sever using python and I am updating a Google Spread Sheet with the CSV data. Sheet 1 and 2 can not be changed they are the master sheets. but sheet3 -10 are free to be updated with the data. I have installed google sheets api but I am looking for a way to call the api. at the moment I have google drive api  in my code. But that only creates a csv into the parent folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, for example, when 2 CSV files are existing, what do you want to do? I cannot know where you want to put each CSV data in sheets 3 to 10 of a Google Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. And. about using Sheets API, how about using googleapis for python? You can see the authorization and the sample script at [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).

Comment: I have Auth google api to work with this project. I have been able to upload the CSV to Google drive folder. But what I am trying to do now is update a single sheet instead. 
So for example lets say I have just one CSV that needs to update TEST Google SpreadSheet in sheet 3. Using google sheets API how would I go about reading the CSV data and then pasting the data into sheet 3 of TEST Spreadsheet?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `what I am trying to do now is update a single sheet instead.`, I understood that you wanted to use only one CSV file and one sheet. About this, I think that when Sheets API is used, the CSV data can be directly put into the Spreadsheet without uploading the file using Drive API. In your situation, are the CSV files required to be uploaded to Google Drive as the files?

Comment: From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your expected method for putting the CSV data into Spreadsheet. So, I proposed 2 patterns. If those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put CSV data to the specific sheet of a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using python.
- You have already been able to get and put values to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

When [googleapis for python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) is used, how about the following sample script?

```py
service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)  # Please use your script for authorization.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please put your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet3"  # Please put the sheet ID of the sheet you want to use.
csv_file = "###"  # Please put the file path of the CSV file you want to use.

f = open(csv_file, "r")
values = [r for r in csv.reader(f)]
request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=sheet_name, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": values}).execute()
```

#### Sample script 2:

When [gspread for python](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/v5.4.0/docs/index.rst) is used, how about the following sample script?

```py
import gspread
import csv

client = gspread.oauth(###) # Please use your script for authorization.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please put your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet3"  # Please put the sheet ID of the sheet you want to use.
csv_file = "###"  # Please put the file path of the CSV file you want to use.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheet_name)
f = open(csv_file, "r")
values = [r for r in csv.reader(f)]
worksheet.update(values)
```

#### Note:

- About both sample scripts, the CSV data is retrieved from a CSV file on your local PC, and the CSV data is converted to a 2-dimensional array and put the array to "Sheet3" of Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. In this sample script, Drive API is not used.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: thanks the script 2 worked good can you also help. right now it updated my existing data how I can add something after the existing filled rows..
for ex: i have 20 rows which are used and update csv data from 21 row!